# Profiling not happening in gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle

I have done below profiling for copying the file from a specific environment directory mentioned during the build command (gradle clean build -x test -Penv=prod) and delete the environment directory after it.

```
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'


task copyProfile(dependsOn:"deleteProfiles") {  
def env = project.hasProperty('env') ? env : 'dev' 
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources/environment/$env"
}

task deleteProfiles(type:Delete) {
delete "src/main/resources/environment"
}

tasks.clean.dependsOn(tasks.deleteProfiles)
```

the deleteProfiles task is working, but copyProfile task

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir "src/main/resources/environment/$env"
```

i.e. copying files from $env directory and put in src/main/resources is not working. Can any one suggest me why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell the task to copy anything...

Change your task to this:

```
task copyProfile(dependsOn:"deleteProfiles") {
  def env = project.findProperty('env') ?: 'dev'
  doLast {
    project.copy {
      from "src/main/resources/environment/$env"
      into sourceSets.main.resources.srcDir
    }
  }
}
```

See [Project.copy(...)](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:copy(groovy.lang.Closure))